# Sending/uploading file to another computer/server

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am working on a Silverlight application to familiarize myself with it.

The application I intend to build has two components: A silverlight web app that I will host (on my home desktop, for now), and a C# app that will run client-side.

The Silverlight app needs to read a file that resides on the client side.

The C# app (which will probably run as a service) needs to send a .txt file (no more than 10kb) to my server every 5-10min or so (will be user configurable).

What is the best way to send the file? (byte stream, or something else?)

How do I configure my server to receive this file? I assume it will involve some IIS configuration, and I could run a C# app that receives the file and saves it in a directory from where the Silverlight app can read it.

Comment: Silverlight **is** client-side; are there 2 client-side components here?

Comment: No, what I meant (maybe I'm getting Silverlight wrong) is I'll place the silverlight in a webpage hosted on my desktop (sever), so a user goes to www.xbonez.com/silverlightapp to use it.

Comment: Right; so you have a web tier, a Silverlight client and a service client

Comment: +1 client sends to client and client process it and sends it to client..#wow

Comment: Hmmm...ok. Seems like I have Silverlight all wrong. What I was assuming was, I can write the Silverlight app and host it on my server. The client only needs to have the Silverlight plugin to view the page, but the Silverlight code resides and executes on my server.

Comment: @xbonez Silverlight is a bit like flash etc; the *download* is hosted on the server, but it executes at the client. I can see why it is confusing, though, as it usual has quite tight coupling to a web-server application.

Comment: @xbonez.. no; Silverlight resides and execute on client not on server..

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I get it now. Ok, I guess Silverlight isn't suited to my project in that case, as I need to receive the file at my server, process it server-side and then display it on a webpage. It will be used by users who aren't sitting at their computer, but want to remotely view the file. I suppose ASP is the way to go, but its not as flashy as Silverlight :(

Comment: Silverlight can send files to the server, so you can use it !

Comment: But, I need to process the files at th server end and display them on the web page and I was hoping to avoid ASP.net. For merely the task of sending the files, I'd prefer to use a C# app as a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a POST request to the server with byte stream and retrieve it on the server.Then process it and show it on your Silverlight app as required.

Also since your silverlight app can directly take file from user and process it in the browser itself if user interaction is required.

Remember Silverlight is a Client Side Technology not Server Side.If you need normal webservice type design where you take file and update some information in database, etc then you need a simple ASP.Net web app not Silverlight.